# Spliting each 1000 rows of my CSV file to a XML File in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, csv, split, marshalling

I have a java program that will read my `CSV` file and convert it to `XML` file, but the issue is that my `CSV` file has lots of rows and the program can not convert all to `XML`, so I need to read each 1000 of my `csv` rows and create a `XMl` for each of them

Below is my code but I can not read each 1000 rows...

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;

public class XMLMainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        UteXmlComunicazione UteXmlComunicazione = new UteXmlComunicazione();        

        //read the csv file and collect all objects
        try {

            String inputfile = "sample.csv"; //  Source File Name.  
              double nol = 1000.0; //  No. of lines to be split and saved in each output file.  
              File file = new File(inputfile);  
              Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);  
              int count = 0;  
              while (scanner.hasNextLine())   
              {  
               scanner.nextLine();  
               count++;  
              }  
              System.out.println("Lines in the file: " + count);     // Displays no. of lines in the input file.  

              double temp = (count/nol);  
              int temp1=(int)temp;  
              int nof=0;  
              if(temp1==temp)  
              {  
               nof=temp1;  
              }  
              else  
              {  
               nof=temp1+1;  
              }  
              System.out.println("No. of files to be generated :"+nof); // Displays no. of files to be generated.  

              FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(inputfile);
              DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);  

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in)); 
                 String strLine;  

             for (int j=1;j<=nof;j++)  
              {  

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {    //get every single line individually in csv file
                String[] value = line.split(";");   //collect the comma separated values into array
                datiCliente datiCliente = new datiCliente();            
                datiCliente.setcfPiva(value[0]);
               ... //  giving the related Node to each of my fields.

            }

        UteXmlComunicazione.setdatiFornitoraClienteList(listForCliente);

        for (int i=1;i<=nol;i++)  
        {  
        //marshaling with java 
        try {

            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(UteXmlComunicazione.class);
            javax.xml.bind.Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true)
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(UteXmlComunicazione, new File("C:/NewFolder/output"+j+".xml"));
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(UteXmlComunicazione, System.out);

        } 
        catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("File is not found");
        }
        }
        }


        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }    
}
```

When I run this code, it creates 180 files (that is correct) but in each of them I have all my rows, not just 1000 rows... and I can not open it.
Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with following solution, this example is related with your previous question. firstly you should split csv file into multiple csv files including with expected row counts. then, get prepared scv file individually and create xml files

People.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name="people")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class People {

    @XmlElement(name="person")
    private List<Person> listPerson;

    public List<Person> getListPerson() {
        return listPerson;
    }
    public void setListPerson(List<Person> listPerson) {
        this.listPerson = listPerson;
    }
}
```

Person.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name="person")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Person {

    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

split csv file into multiple csv files and create xml file separately,

```
public class Marshaller {

    int rowCount;
    int fileCount = 1;
    PrintWriter writer;
    int lineCount;
    int index;
    String line;
    ArrayList<Person> list;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Marshaller marshaller = new Marshaller();
        marshaller.readCSV();   //split csv file into multiple csv files
        marshaller.readMultipleCSV(); //create XML files using multiple csv files
    }

    public void readCSV(){
        try {
            BufferedReader buffeReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("inputCSV.csv"));
            while ((line = buffeReader.readLine()) != null) {   //get every single line individually in csv file

                rowCount++;
                if(rowCount == 1){
                    openNewFile();
                }

                String[] value = line.split(",");   //collect the comma separated values into array
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                stringBuilder.append(value[0]+','+value[1]+','+value[2]+'\n');  //append the array values to stringBuilder with comma separation
                writer.write(stringBuilder.toString()); //write individual data line into csv file

                if(rowCount == 100){
                    fileCount++;
                    closeWriter();
                }
            }
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void openNewFile(){
        try {
            writer = new PrintWriter(new File("your_multiple_csv_file_output_path/"+fileCount+".csv")); //create a new csv file
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void closeWriter(){
        writer.close(); //close a csv file
        rowCount = 0;
    }


    public void readMultipleCSV(){
        ArrayList<File> xmlFileList = new ArrayList();
        System.out.println(xmlFileList.size());
        xmlFileList.addAll(Arrays.asList(new File("your_multiple_csv_file_output_path").listFiles()));  //add all generated csv files into array list

        for (int i = 0; i < xmlFileList.size(); i++) {
            People people = new People();
            ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList();
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(xmlFileList.get(i).toString()));  //get csv file separately
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {    //get every single line individually in csv file
                    String[] value = line.split(",");   //collect the comma separated values into array
                    Person person = new Person();
                    person.setId(value[0]); //first element of an array is id
                    person.setFirstName(value[1]);  //second element of an array is firstName
                    person.setLastName(value[2]);   //third element of an array is lastName
                    list.add(person);   //add person object into the list
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            people.setListPerson(list);
            prepareXML(people, i);
        }
    }

    public void prepareXML(People people, int csvFileNo){
        //marshaling with java
        try {

            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(People.class);
            javax.xml.bind.Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(people, new File("your_xml_file_output_path/output "+(csvFileNo+1)+".xml"));
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(people, System.out);

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

inputCSV.csv (without columns' names)

```
1,yong,mook kim
2, Alez, Aunritod
3,yong,mook kim
.
.
.
```

Comment: Hi Lakshan, Thans for your reponse. Actually I am not looking for record number 1000. my csv file has million records and I want to split it and read at everytime each 1000 or 2000 records together and convert them to XML and continue till the end of file

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, please refer above modified answer

Comment: Hi Lakshan, Thanks again for your help. I tested this code with 150 lines of my CSV and tried to split them in every 100 lines. So it creates two CSV file, one of them with 100 lines and the other with 50 lines, but when it created XML, the first XML has 100 Person Object, but the second has 150.. I mean it merge them together...

Comment: do you want to create separate xml file for every single line in csv file?

Comment: No, for each csv file. I mean with your code, it creates me two csv file completely ok, but when want to create XML for each of these CSV files, the csv1 convert completely to XML, but XML2 contains CSV1+CVS2 ... I mean it add the previous lines also in the second XML

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, please refer modified answer. it creates separate XML file for every csv file. thanks